# Flutter Web check if cookies are enabled?

Tags: flutter, dart, cookies

According to Dart, there is a method that exists called "cookieEnabled" which returns a bool depending on whether cookies are enabled or not. All well and good except I cannot figure out how to use it.

I have tried:

```
if (html.Navigator.cookieEnabled)
```

but this says "member cannot be accessed using static access.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should obtain instance of navigator first, as cookieEnabled is **not** static getter:

```dart
if (html.window.navigator.cookieEnabled)
```

Comment: I believe you meant as `cookieEnabled` is **not** a static getter.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: can you tell me in brief. I didn't get how can I use this?